# Is there a way to keep a sublist synchronized to the contents of a master list?

Tags: c#, list, sublist

I will have one 'master list' (preferably of type BindingList). In another class I have a sublist, which is composed of certain elements of the 'master list'. Each instance of the class has different elements. Is there a way to keep each of the sublists synchronized with the 'master list'?

Comment: Can you define **synchronized**? Can you give an example of master list elements and then the sublist elements and what you want to keep synchronized?

Comment: As in, if an object in the 'master list' gets changed, any sublist that contains that object will update the change

Comment: If they are not value types, they will update the change. Objects in .NET are passed by reference. You shouldn't worry about this at all. An object can belong to many collections, as long as it's the same reference (and it should be if you haven't done cloning), then the object will be **"synchronized"**.

Comment: OK I see (I come from C++ so this is always mysterious to me). 
So if I have BindingList<Person> master_list in my main class, and in instances of another class (call it UserForm) I have BindingList<Person> sub_list, how would the sub_lists be populated (and later elements removed), would I just pass master_list[some int] into the add function?

Comment: Correct. sub_list.Add(master_list[some_index]) is perfectly legal.

Comment: Everything works great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create that type of list you need by extending your list and add composite objects that you also synchronize whenever you update your "main" list.

Here is how I would do it in java, you can do the same in c# but right know i dont remember exact syntax. You could ofcourse extend what ever list type you like.

```
public class MyList extends ArrayList {
    private List<Object> someOtherList;
    public MyList(){
        super();
    }

    public void setSyncList(List<Object> list){
        someOtherList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Object arg0) {
        boolean b = super.add(arg0);
        someOtherList.add(arg0); // here you can decide what action should be done to the syncList, it might not want to add all elements, same goes for the remove below
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object arg0) {
        boolean b = super.remove(arg0);
        someOtherList.remove(arg0);
        return b;
    }

}
```

Comment: How would you incorporate having multiple sublists? as well as modification of the arg0?

Comment: I would make the someOtherList into a list of lists. Then I would make all these lists implement an interface for the actions add and remove and more if needed

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you need is ObseravleCollection collection.

Please refer this for more details
1. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLListVsOCollections.aspx
2. http://karlhulme.wordpress.com/2007/03/04/synchronizedobservablecollection-and-bindablecollection/